# How To Change the Background Image of my Blog

Tags: html, image, blogs, blogger

I've been trying to change the blank background of my new blog and I have tried to do it the easy way but, I am not able to. I thought I'd attempt the more difficult approach and I the code below and I don't know how to integrate this into my blog.

```html
<Group description="Body">
  <Variable name="body.background.color" description="Body background color" type="color" default="#f7f7f7"  value="#f6f6f6"/>
  <Variable name="body.background" description="Background" type="background" color="#f7f7f7" default="$(color) none repeat scroll top left"  value="$(color) none repeat scroll top left"/>
  <Variable name="body.text.font" description="Font" type="font" default="$(generalFont)"  value="400 16px Ubuntu, sans-serif"/>
  <Variable name="body.text.color" description="Color" type="color" default="#000000"  value="#000000"/>
  <Variable name="body.link.color" description="Link color" type="color" default="$(keycolor)"  value="#729c0b"/>
  <Variable name="body.link.visited.color" description="Visited Link color" type="color" default="$(body.link.color)"  value="#729c0b"/>
  <Variable name="body.link.hover.color" description="Link hover color" type="color" default="$(body.link.color)"  value="#729c0b"/>
  <Variable name="body.button.font" description="Button font" type="font" default="$(textButtonFont)"  value="500 12px Ubuntu, sans-serif"/>
  <Variable name="body.button.color" description="Button color" type="color" default="$(keycolor)"  value="#729c0b"/>
</Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the `color` in `type="background" color="#f7f7f7"` to another `hex` value ? Or do you want to change the background color to background image ?

Comment: background image

Answer (score 0):

On the third line(body background) there is a `color="#f7f7f7"` . Change it whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Change the 3rd line as follows -

```
<Variable default="$(color) url(IMAGE_URL) none repeat scroll top left"  value="$(color) url(IMAGE_URL) none repeat scroll top left" name="body.background" description="Background" type="background" color="#f7f7f7" />
```

Replace `IMAGE_URL` with the actual URL of the image you want as background

Comment: Invalid variable declaration in page skin: This is not a recognized value for background repeat. Value must be one of: "repeat", "repeat-x", "repeat-y", "no-repeat". Input: none Hide notification